# Select all field values of an observable array in a comma separated string

Tags: jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I've got an observableArray like this:

```
self.DisplayMessageCollection = ko.observableArray();
```

I'm getting a collection and pushing items to that `DisplayMessageCollection` like this:

```
self.DisplayMessageCollection.push({                            
                        messageid: msgid,
                        loader: 'block',
                        uploadopacity: 'uploadopacity',
                        sentstatus: 'Wait',
                        Chattype: self.ToChatType()
                    });
```

I need to get all the `messageid` field values as a comma seperated string from that array.

I know I can *loop* all the items and get `messageid` values. But I want to know if we can query on the `observableArray`, i.e. somehow do a *single query* to get all the field values as a comma seperated string?

Comment: you can use `map` and then `join` on the underlying array `self.DisplayMessageCollection().map(function(i) { return i.messageid }).join(",")`

Comment: Elegant answer . @satya that should work . cheers

Comment: @nemesv You should post that comment as an answer I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in [`map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the underlying array and then  and you can use the [`join` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get your comma separated string:

```
self.DisplayMessageCollection().map(function(i) { return i.messageid }).join(",")
```

If you need this logic multiple times you can create a [helper function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html) for the observable array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KO utils to map your array and join the values. Like this:

```
var messages = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.DisplayMessageCollection(), function(item) {
     return item.messageid;
}).join(',');
```

However, this is practically the same as Nemesv's solution.